# Comparing large and small populations

Tags: binomial-distribution, small-sample, estimators

Here is a hypothetical that mimics my actual data (sensitive so cannot post actual details). I have 149 students in a class. In preparation for the final exam (which is pass/fail, NOT ranked), I held 3 in-class review sessions. 140 of the students attended all three, 5 attended 2/3 sessions, 3 attended 1/3 sessions, and 1 student didn't attend anything.

Here is a breakdown of test results:

3 sessions: 36/140 failed

2 sessions: 3/5 failed

1 session: 1/3 failed

0 sessions: 0/1 failed

I want to know, what is the best way to test statistical difference between the students who attended all three vs. each other group. The way I have set this up is by using the group that attended all three sessions to estimate the failure rate, then use the binomial distribution to test to see if the failure rate of each other group is different than the estimated failure rate. Is this the best way to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all carry out an overall test on the 2 by 4 table using chi-squared or the extended form of the Fisher exact test. If this was significant I would compare each category with the reference. You could fit a model using logistic regression as well of course. Note that you may run into some problems with your never attender category as you have a zero there.

Comment: Thanks! After learning more about the Fisher exact test it seems like the best way to analyze these data!